# AFNetworking and submitting html form with user validated captcha

Tags: objective-c, session, captcha, afnetworking

I've trying to be able to login in a website which has an html form with a captcha. The way I've been trying to do it is fetching the html of the login form, showing the captcha to a user, who will put it in a textfield and then I'm trying to submit the form.

The error I'm always getting is invalid key code, so I'm guessing the problem is the captcha I fetch in the first instance, isn't valid for the second one... Any ideas how I could do this?

The webpage is Fanfiction, and I'm doing this as a personal proyect and see if I'm capable of exporting my list of favorites and follows.

I do this in order to show the captcha to the user.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.fanfiction.net"];
self.httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

[self.httpClient getPath:@"/login.php" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    TFHpple * doc       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:responseObject];
    NSArray * elements  = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//img[@id='xcaptcha']"];

    TFHppleElement * element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];

    [self.captchaView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[element objectForKey:@"src"]]];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { }];
```

And then, whenthe user has entered the captcha code in a textfield and pressed a UIButton, I do this

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            kFFNMail,       @"email",
                            kFFNPass,       @"password",
                            self.captchaField.text,     @"captcha",
                        nil];

NSURLRequest *postRequest = [self.httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                  path:@"/login.php"
                                                            parameters:params
                                             constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) { }];

/*
// I think this is the same as the one before in this case
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:@"/login.php"
                                                  parameters:params2];
*/

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    TFHpple * doc       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:responseObject];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { }];

[operation start];
```

If is of any indication, I have this working in a ruby script like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require "highline/import"

a = Mechanize.new
a.get('https://www.fanfiction.net/login.php') do |page|

  images = page.search("#xcaptcha")
  a.get(images.first.attributes["src"]).save "captcha.jpg"

  # I read the saved image,and enter the captcha code
  captcha = ask "Input captcha: "

  # Submit the login form
  my_page = page.form_with(:action => '/login.php') do |f|
    f.email     = my_mail
    f.password  = my_pass
    f.captcha   = captcha
  end.click_button

  # already logged!
  a.get('https://www.fanfiction.net/alert/story.php') do |page|
    page.links.each do |link|
      text = link.text.strip
      next unless text.length > 0
      puts text
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, turns out I was doing everything ok, just that I had forgotten one extra parameter in the form, a hidden input which had the id of the captcha. 
I just needed to capture the id at the same time that I captured the captcha image, and then send it in the form POST as an extra parameter.

Hope this helps anyone.